# High-vote questions need the 1K treatment

Tags: feature-request, voting, design

There are [three questions on SO with over 999 vote score](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes). It's probably time for the 1K treatment to keep the vote counter from looking so crowded.

[image: SO crowded]

Comment: Alternate plan: downvote all those posts until they're under 1000 again

Comment: @Michael - wasn't there a question somewhere that we were trying to keep at 256?

Comment: What about comma separation instead, i.e. 1,006? Oh wait, that would crowd it even more...

Comment: If a question has more than 1,100 votes, it should say 1.1K votes to show it is in the 1,100 - 1,199 range of votes.

Comment: Do we really need to worry about this extremely rare case at all?

Answer (score 9):

I'm hesitant about it for the questions list, but I believe it's a bad idea on the question itself. Views and such are one-directional, indirect effects. Votes are bidirectional and reversible effects

The effects of a vote, up or down, should be immediately visible to the user when they cast a vote. Condensing it to "Xk" will result in requiring a hover or some other extra step to get this confirmation. And the tooltip already is used for the split vote count, so that'd just be moving the clutter to another spot.

Comment: I think when a question has 1k+ upvotes, we can pretty much determine that is a good question.

Comment: I think when a question has 1k+ upvotes, we can pretty much determine that is a poll or a list.

Comment: I *definitely* agree with @Grace Note!

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't call it crowded, it actually looks fine. Besides, votes matter and rounding to the nearest thousand isn't what I would call accurate.

Now we just need to wait for 1 question to reach 10000, then we can complain about size

Comment: OK. I'll be happy to post one just so we can see what 10,000 looks like. Or just go ahead and use any of my existing questions. Feel free to try it on my answers, too.

Comment: @Jon It'd probably be faster to just downvote one of your posts to -1000

Comment: @Michael - I'd make it up in sympathy votes :)

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be to use a smaller font size.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another alternative would be to right justify the number with the right-side vertices of the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

And another alternative would be [a logarithmic vote count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59330/would-a-logarithmic-votes-display-be-useful), leaving a ~1000 question at a score of 10 to 11...